# Slashes in angular routes

Tags: angular-routing

Can you have slashes in angular routes to make it look like subfolders?

I've got this sort of setup

[image]

I'd like to makepages at `/users/index` and `/users/groups` etc.

In `users.routing.module.ts` I have:

```
  Shell.childRoutes([
    {
      path: '', component: IndexComponent, data: { roles: ['Administrator'] },
      children: [
        { path: 'users', component: UsersComponent, data: { roles: ['Administrator'] } },
        { path: 'groups', component: GroupsComponent, data: { roles: ['Administrator'] } },
        { path: 'roles', component: RolesComponent, data: { roles: ['Administrator'] } }
      ]
    }
  ])
];
```

Howver,

```
<p><a [routerLink]="users/users">Users</a></p>
```

makes the link come out as `NaN`. WTF?

Is it possible to have URLs with slashes in them or do I have to make everything as `/component`?

Answer (score 0):

It is Nan because you have not defined any route as users/users , try changing one route path as -

```
{ path: 'users/users', component: UsersComponent, data: { roles: ['Administrator'] } },
```

Comment: So `path` is aways a full path from `/`? I imagined that maybe `children` would build up the path?

Comment: @RichardBarraclough what are you trying to achieve? Tell me that the i will try to help you.

Comment: In Angular I can only make pages with URLs like `/foo`.

How can I make a page at `/foo/bar`?